# How to solve this optimally?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, graph-algorithm

I have a tree of n vertices `n<=10^5` where each vertex has a score[i] and q queries `q<=10^5` 
Each query has two parameters u and L, I need to find

```
sum(score[i]) for all i where lca(i,u)=u and dist(u,i)=L
```

I can solve each query in `O(n)` time using bfs but it's not efficient. How can I optimize this? I have spent much time on this but could not find a way to solve it in `nlogn` time for all queries.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let the `u` be at depth `h`. Then what we need to find is the sum of scores of all vertices at depth `h + L` in the `u`'s subtree (it's just a reformulation of the problem).

1. Let's store a vector of vertices sorted by their entrance time for each level.
2. The subtree is contiguous segment in the vector for depth `h + L`.
3. We can find its borders using binary search (something like `lower_bound(at_depth[h + L].begin(), at_depth[h + L].end(), entrance_time[u])`, `upper_bound(at_depth[h + L].begin(), at_depth[h + L].end(), leave_time[u])` in C++).
4. The answer is the sum of scores in this range. We can find it in `O(1)` using prefix sums.

This solution requires to binary searches and two prefix sums look ups per query, so it works in `O(log N)` time.

Comment: How will you calculate leave time?

Comment: @PremSingh When the vertex is about to popped of the stack (that is, in the very end of the dfs function), we do leave_time[v] = timer++